# Scattering amplitude Green's function integral

Tags: quantum-mechanics, scattering, integration

On page 208 of Weinberg's QM book, he calculates the following integral

\begin{align}
G_k (\vec{x}-\vec{y})
=& \int \frac{d^3 q}{(2\pi \hbar)^3} \frac{e^{i\vec{q} \cdot (\vec{x}-\vec{y})}} {E(k)-E(q)+i\epsilon} \\
=& \frac{4\pi}{(2\pi)^3}\int_0^{\infty} q^2 dq \frac{\sin(q|\vec{x}-\vec{y}|)}{q|\vec{x}-\vec{y}|}\frac{2m/\hbar^2}{k^2-q^2+i\epsilon} \, .
\end{align}

It is clear that he is integrating in spherical coordinates. However, I don't see how where the

$$\frac{\sin(q|\vec{x}-\vec{y}|)}{q|\vec{x}-\vec{y}|}$$

comes from. Can someone explain?

Comment: I think you should just try to work out the integral yourself to see where it comes from. Have your tried that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $d^3 q = dq q^2 d\theta d\phi \sin\theta$ and integrate over the angular variables. The only angular dependence in the integrand is in $e^{i \vec{q} \cdot ( \vec{x}-\vec{y}) } = e^{i q r \cos\theta}$ where I've defined $r = | \vec{x} - \vec{y} |$. Then, we have
$$
\int_0^{2\pi} d\phi \int_0^\pi d\theta \sin\theta e^{i q r \cos\theta}
$$ 
There is no $\phi$ dependence so that just gives $2\pi$. For the $\theta$ integral defined new integration variable $t = \cos\theta$. Then, the above becomes
$$
2\pi \int_{-1}^{1}  dt  e^{i q r t} = \frac{2\pi}{i q r }  e^{i q r t}  \bigg|_{-1}^1 = \frac{2\pi}{ i q r } \left[ e^{i q r } - e^{- i q r } \right] = \frac{4\pi }{ q r } \sin(qr)  = \frac{4 \pi \sin \left( q | \vec{x} - \vec{y} | \right) }{ q | \vec{x} - \vec{y} | } 
$$

Comment: Isn't this an explicit solution to a homework-type question?

Comment: Oh of course! Sorry I didn't mean for it to be a homework question. I was just trying to understand the derivation from the book.